# How do I scale up/down a running Flink cluster?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm running Flink on Kubernetes now. I assume if I update the replicas of TaskManager deployment, Kubernetes scales up/down the number of TM pods for me, but I'm not sure if that is all I need to do. Do I need to do anything else to make the job adapt to the more/less TMs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache Flink does not, by default, rescale in response to changes in the number of task managers.

There are various schemes for how Flink rescales in a K8s environment. One, referred to as "active mode", is where Flink knows what resources it wants, and works with K8s to obtain/release resources accordingly. See [how to deploy Flink natively on Kubernetes](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/resource-providers/native_kubernetes/) for details.

Another scheme, referred to as "reactive mode", is what you appear to be hoping for: Flink scales itself to use whatever resources have been made available. See [Elastic Scaling](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/elastic_scaling/) for details.

You can also deploy Flink on Kubernetes in what is effectively a containerized version of a standalone deployment. In such an environment, rescaling involves these steps:

1. Stop the job while taking a savepoint
2. Resume the job from the savepoint, having arranged for the new cluster to be appropriately sized

The [Flink Operations Playground has a step-by-step example](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/getting-started/docker-playgrounds/flink-operations-playground.html#upgrading--rescaling-a-job) of how to do rescaling in a docker-compose-based deployment.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is a great help!