# TaskManager scaling in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, scaling

I'm using the HA for the flink. While scaling the TM from 1 -> 2, both the TM's are registered with the resource manager but only one TM is offered the reserved slot and the other TM is idle instead of 2 TM being offered the slots.

UPDATE 1: After using the reactive mode, scaling is working fine but there are few limitations, it's restarting for every TM addition, not updating the some metrics(checkpointing, uptime and downtime ) with a log "Name collision: Group already contains a Metric with the name"

Using latest stable Flink Version:'1.13.2'

Comment: Adding more slots doesn't automatically scale the running job(s) unless you are using the reactive scheduler. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58807295/2000823 for pointers.

Comment: Thanks, but with those changes scaling is working fine but the limitations are it's restarting for every TM addition and not updating the checkpoint metrics and uptime and downtime metrics.

Comment: Flink can only rescale by restarting from a state snapshot (savepoint or checkpoint). There is no way to avoid this.